# Cambiar ruta node_modules en una funcion

Tags: javascript, nodejs, gulp

¿Es posible el cambiar la ruta del nodule_modules dentro de una función?

Tengo una estructura en gulpfile.js en la cuál hay diferentes scripts para diferentes tareas: minificar, unir, optimizar, etc.

Pero tambien hay una funcion en la cuál realizo versión de la web, en la cual salen diferentes portales, en los que solo cambia el CSS.

La cosa es que ahora tengo que copiar la carpeta node modules en cada uno de los subdirectorios y me gustaria poder cambiar su ruta para no tener que hacer este paso que me hace perder muchisimo tiempo.

La estructura es:

```
/CarpetaRaiz
    /src
    /dist
    /node_modules
    /Versiones
       /VersionWeb1
          /src (con sus CSS)
          /dist
       /VersionWeb2
          /src (con sus CSS)
          /dist
       /VersionWeb3
          /src (con sus CSS)
          /dist
       /VersionWeb4
          /src (con sus CSS)
          /dist
```

Y aquí viene el problema, puesto que encada tura VersionWebX tengo que copiar la carpeta node_modules, ahora mismo hay 16 versiones, imaginaros el tiempo que se pierde copiando esa carpeta 16 veces.

¿Existe la manera de optimizar el script, cogiendo en la funcion "versiones" la ruta hacia el node modules original?

**Edit 1**

Trabajo sobre un equipo con Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el servidor es Linux, puedes crear un symlink en lugar de copiar toda la carpeta:

```
(desde CarpetaRaiz)

ln -s ./node_modules ./VersionWeb1/node_modules
```

[Para saber más sobre symlinks en Linux](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/ln.htm)

Si el servidor es Windows, este sería el comando:

```
mklink /D ./VersionWeb1/node_modules ./node_modules
```

[Para saber más sobre symlinks en windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)

Comment: el servidor es Windows

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con el comando para Windows, aunque tengo que decir que ese no lo he probado nunca, espero que te sirva

Comment: Aún no te he comentado nada definitivo porque no he podido probarlo, en que lo haga, te lo digo y si es correcto, cierro respuesta.

Comment: Genial, gracias por escribir, ya me cuentas que tal.

Comment: Eres un crack, ha funcionado a la perfección.

Comment: Gracias! Me alegro de que funcione!